# Ubuntu DNS Issues

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns, resolv.conf

Using Ubuntu 18.04 - My DNS suddenly stopped working. Just had installed Docker and minikube etc - not sure if this caused it - no idea.

I can ping an IP (like Google) but **cannot** ping google.com.

$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

$ nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Tried a couple of things

```
$ sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
$ sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
$ sudo systemctl restart resolvconf

  Failed to restart resolvconf.service: Unit resolvconf.service not found.

$ sudo systemctl stop networking`
Failed to stop networking.service: Unit networking.service not loaded
```

Tried (re)install resolve.conf - **did not work**

```
sudo apt install resolvconf 
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?


sudo apt install resolvconf --fix-missing
E: Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap
```

Thanks

Comment: the service is `systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service`

Comment: `resolvectl status` gives info

Comment: `systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service` - no output. `resolvectl status` **resolvectl: command not found**. My apt is not working so cant install anything. But problem remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS in Ubuntu (and probably others) has gotten.. complicated.

First off, to get yourself back online in the short term, do the following:

```bsh
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

This will point you directly at Google's DNS servers and bypass whatever is happening on your system.

Under normal circumstances (at least on 18.04 server edition) `netplan.io`, `resolvconf`, `systemd-networkd`, and `systemd-resolved` all have to be happy with each other for DNS to work.  The first step would be to see if `systemd-resolved` is working.  Does `sudo systemd-resolve --status` return the correct info?  How about `sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved`?  If `systemd-resolved` is running correctly, edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and point the nameserver at "127.0.0.53".  Are things still working?  Then `resolvconf` might be the culprit.

Comment: `echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf` - this gets me up. `sudo systemd-resolve --status` - returns. So how do I set/edit the resolv.conf - do I install (apt), or just edit the resolv.conf. Do I I let both nameserver 8.8.8.8 and nameserver 127.0.0.53, or just 127.0.0.53?

Comment: I just added these 3: `nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4 nameserver 127.0.0.53`  - seems to be working

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` used to be just a plain file that was easy to maintain.  The downside was that DHCP had a hard time configuring it so `resolvconf` became a thing.  Then `systemd` decided to create a local caching server (`systemd-resolved`).  You only *need* `/etc/resolv.conf` but the rest of that chain is useful.  If you pare back to only "127.0.0.53" as your sole nameserver, does it still work?

Comment: Pared back to only 127.0.0.53 - it works. So I will leave that one only for now. Still wondering what caused all this - had installed some software - nothing to do with networing/DNS etc